# How to tell the association of two variables in a contingency table without using chi square test?

Tags: conditional-probability, contingency-tables, association-measure

In my notes:

Two variables in a contingency table are independent if **the conditional distribution of one
variable is the same for all values of the other variable**

I think this is somehow trying to relate to conditional probability, specifically

P(A|B) = P(A) or P(A AND B) = P(A) P(B)

But I don't understand the bolded part or connect how it has anything to do with conditional probability.

Comment: Note that this is exactly what Chi-square is about, only written in probability rather than frequency terms.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A|_B)$ is the conditional probability of $A$, conditional on the value of $B$, so $P(A|_B)=P(A)$ means that the conditional probability of $A$, conditional on the value of $B$, is equal to $P(A)$.

So  $P(A|_B)=P(A)$ means that the conditional probability of the variable $A$ is the same (namely $P(A)$), whatever the value of $B$.

Comment: How does the conditional distribution relate to conditional probability? I can sort of sense it, but an answer that relates both of them would be helpful.

Comment: Simply stated the distribution is the set of the probabilities for each event.